# Reference widget using id in Kivy (kv language)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following in KV language (simplified example):
My issue is with the last line (on_release).

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyCustomWidgets>:
    
    ListView:
        id: my_listview
    
    
<MainScreen>:
    
    Button:
        text: "Choose File"
        on_release: Factory.FileChooserDialog().open()
    
    MyCustomWidgets:
            
    
<FileChooserDialog@ModalView>:
    
    FileChooserIconView:
        id: filechooser

    Button:
        text: "OK"
        on_release: app.root.add_to_listview("Sample Text", app.root.ids.my_listview)
```

In Python, I have:

```
class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    def add_to_listview(self, thelistview):
        # For testing purposes.
        print(type(thelistview))
```

In KV, on the last line, I'm trying to run a python method which adds a string to a `ListView` that has an id of `my_listview`.

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: I don't understand the example, why are these rules indented? and why do they have id, it doesn't make sense for a rule to have an id, since ids are local to the rule…

Comment: @Tshirtman: the idents was a mistake, I fixed the sample and only put the id's where it matters. I basically want to add the selected path/filename to the ListView (from filechooser), but I'm not sure how to reach the ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Kivy *ObjectProperty*, `my_listview = ObjectProperty(None)` and hook it up (`my_listview: my_listview`) to the `id: my_listview` defined in the kv file. Please refer to the example and output for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyCustomWidgets(BoxLayout):
    my_listview = ObjectProperty(None)


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):

    def add_to_listview(self, *args, thelistview):
        # For testing purpose
        print(self)
        print(args[0])
        print(thelistview)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Reference widget using id in Kivy (kv language)"

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory


<MyCustomWidgets>:
    my_listview: my_listview
    ListView:
        id: my_listview


<MainScreen>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Button:
        text: "Choose File"
        on_release: Factory.FileChooserDialog().open()

    MyCustomWidgets:
        id: my_cw


<FileChooserDialog@ModalView>:

    id: filechooser

    Button:
        text: "OK"
        on_release:
            app.root.add_to_listview("Sample Text", thelistview=app.root.ids.my_cw.my_listview)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What if MyCustomWidgets: has a BoxLayout as a parent? In my real code, the ListView is inside a BoxLayout. How would I reference the ListView then?

Example: 
class MyCustomWidgets(BoxLayout):
    pass

Comment: I have updated my example to reflect MyCustomWidgets class is a BoxLayout and ListView is a child widget inside the boxlayout. Please refer to my example for details in regards to referencing the ListView.